# error in sqlalchemy after replacing count query with exists query

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

```
class SourcetoPort(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = 'source_to_port'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    port_no        = Column(Integer)
    src_address    = Column(String,index=True)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, src_address,port_no):
        """"""
        self.src_address = src_address
        self.port_no     = port_no


  def act_like_switch (self, packet, packet_in):
    """
    Implement switch-like behavior.
    """
    # Learn the port for the source MAC
    #print "RECIEVED FROM PORT ",packet_in.in_port , "SOURCE ",packet.src
    # create a Session
    #Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    #session = Session()
    self.mac_to_port[packet.src]=packet_in.in_port
    #if self.mac_to_port.get(packet.dst)!=None:
    print "count for dst",session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=str(packet.dst)).count(),str(packet.dst)
    #if session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=str(packet.dst)).count():
    if session.query(exists().where(SourcetoPort.src_address == str(packet.dst))).scalar() is not None:
           #send this packet
           print "got info from the database"
           q_res = session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=str(packet.dst)).first()
           self.send_packet(packet_in.buffer_id, packet_in.data,q_res.port_no, packet_in.in_port)
           #create a flow modification message
           msg = of.ofp_flow_mod()
           #set the fields to match from the incoming packet
           msg.match = of.ofp_match.from_packet(packet)
           #send the rule to the switch so that it does not query the controller again.
           msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_output(port=q_res.port_no))
           #push the rule
           self.connection.send(msg)
    else:
           #flood this packet out as we don't know about this node.
           print "flooding the first packet"
           self.send_packet(packet_in.buffer_id, packet_in.data,
                       of.OFPP_FLOOD, packet_in.in_port)
           #self.matrix[(packet.src,packet.dst)]+=1      
           entry = SourcetoPort(src_address=str(packet.src) , port_no=packet_in.in_port)
           #add the record to the session object
           session.add(entry)
           #add the record to the session object
           session.commit()
```

I have this peice of code.I replaced

```
#if session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=str(packet.dst)).count():
```

with

```
if session.query(exists().where(SourcetoPort.src_address == str(packet.dst))).scalar() is not None:

Now I am getting the following error.


  File "/home/karthik/pox/tutorial.py", line 86, in act_like_switch
    self.send_packet(packet_in.buffer_id, packet_in.data,q_res.port_no, packet_in.in_port)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'port_no'
^CINFO:core:Going down...
```

The above piece of code used to work with count query.Why is it now working with exists query.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: exists() does not return True or False ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As francis-avila explained in his brilliant [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348493/query-from-sqlalchemy-returns-attributeerror-nonetype-object) there was issue in logic with `exists()...scalar() is not None`. It returns True or False - so it always return not None. Sorry it was my mistake while suggesting how to use exists in SQLAlchemy yesterday.

Other that that your code is correct and should work after changing logic of using `exists()` query results from:

```
if session.query(exists().where(SourcetoPort.src_address == str(packet.dst))).scalar() is not None:
```

to

```
if session.query(exists().where(SourcetoPort.src_address == str(packet.dst))).scalar():
```

Approach with using exists()...one() described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348493/query-from-sqlalchemy-returns-attributeerror-nonetype-object) and handling exception would work too. Just keep in mind that handling exception is always more expensive operation (use more cpu cycles) in python then just doing condition check. If your application is not performance critical - using try/catch exception handling would be just fine.